# enable drop down menu in super fish theme

Tags: css, z-index, superfish

How do i enable drop down menu in this theme http://www.html5xcss3.com/2014/03/yourhome-html5-theme.html

```
<nav class="horizontal-nav full-width horizontalNav-notprocessed">
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index-1.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="index-1.html">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="index-2.html">Gallery</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="index-1.html">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="index-1.html">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="index-3.html">Enquiry</a></li>
<li><a href="index-4.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

i get a drop down but it is hidden behind the banner.....

i have tried changing css z-index property but its not working......

someone help me on this

Comment: Please post fiddle or [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) demo including CSS.

Comment: sry i have not used it but u can see the problem here http://shop.kenosys.in/demo1/ gallery

Comment: Yes I got it and also posted the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this CSS.

```
.menu_block {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of the elements to the maximum(e.g. 99999)

Try this:

```
ul.sf-menu
{
    z-index: 99999; 
}
```